# git add with filter and some exception

Tags: regex, git

I want add into the stage area all `*.ini` files, except some `*_old.ini` files. I remember from the `.gitignore` file about the `!` char existing and I want use it for `git add`. So, it is two regexes: `\*.ini` and `\!\*_old.ini`. Can I merge these regexes for `git add` like a logic `AND` operator?

I know, I can do this:

```
git add \*.ini
git rm -r --cached \*_old.ini
```

But can it be written like *a single* filter for `git add` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add the file-pattern to ignore (`*_old.ini`) to your `.gitignore` file and add the files.

```
$ ls
foo.ini
bar_old.ini
$ cat .gitignore
*_old.ini
$ git status
foo.ini
$ git add "*.ini"
$ git commit -m "added .ini-files (ignoring *_old.ini)"
```